# link need to open when click on title column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, development

Some trick request came. We had list with columns as "Title", "Owner", "Description", "External Path", "Requester". In "title" column, we have given name of item, under "Description" some matter given and "external path" column, we have given some URL.

Now our request is when we click on "Title" column, it need to open "External path" column link. Hope someone got my point. Is it possible achieve my request?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can create a calculated column with structure something like : `<a href="[External Path]" target="_blank">[Title]</a>`

Comment: By keeping both fields mandatory and returning calculated field as number so that hyperlink will get created.

Comment: Thanks mate, calculated column options not working.

Comment: What is the exact problem? are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

If the "External Path" field is a single text field, we can add the following code into a script editor in list view page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var fieldContext = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Available field on List View 
        "LinkTitle": { "View": fieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function fieldTemplate(ctx) { 
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];     
    var externalPath = ctx.CurrentItem["External_x0020_Path"];  
    return "<a href='"+$(externalPath).text()+"' target='_blank'>"+title+"</a>"
}
</script>
```

[image]

If the "External Path" field is a multiple line of text field, and not in the list view. We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("div[field='LinkTitle']>a").attr("href","#");
    $("div[field='LinkTitle']>a").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("div[field='LinkTitle']>a").click(function(){
        var listGUID=$(".ms-listviewtable").attr("id").split("}-")[0].split("{")[1];
        var itemId=$(this).parent().attr("id");
        OpenExternalPath(listGUID,itemId);
    });
});
function OpenExternalPath(listGUID,itemId){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listGUID+"')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var externalPath=data.d.External_x0020_Path;
            if($(externalPath).text()!=""){
                window.open($(externalPath).text(), '_blank');
            }           
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, mate, i tried your code but its not working for me. its showing "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
" on the script editor webpart

Comment: its working, if we have two columns as "test" and "External Path". But in my case 8 column are present. its not working if we have more columns. Please suggest me for more columns.

Comment: I suggest you provide the name and field type of all the columns for further research.

Comment: we have 15 columns in a list, 1 image with "hyperlink or picture" type column, 2 Title with "single line text", 3 Description with "Multiple lines of text", 4 Owner with "Person or group", 5 Condition with "single line text", 6 Status with "Choice" type, 7 Process with "Choice" type,8 external path with "Multiple lines of text", 9 internal path with "Multiple lines of text", 10 Condition with "single line text", 11Data with "multiple line of text", 12 Control with "Multiple line of text", 13 date with "date and time" 14 number with "single line text", 15 request with hyperlink.

Comment: The "External Path" is multiple line of text? Do you want to store multiple link in this field? Example, if you have two links, which one do you want to open when click the "Title" column?

Comment: its multiple lines of text, but only one link will be provided on the "external path" column. And also list view attached for reference.  Note: external path column is not in our view but it exists on the list. please suggest now.

Comment: Check my updated reply above.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a "Hyperlink" column and hide the title column on the form and list view.

[image]

[image]

**Or** you can use jquery to get the href and replace your title columns href.
[image]

```
<script src="/...../SiteAssets/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td > a').each(function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("TEST: " + getLink);
        $(this).parent().prev().prev().children().children().removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick").attr("href",getLink);
    });
});
</script>
```

This will just swap out the href for each row. Might need some cleaning up of the code, but it should do the trick. In my case the link column was located right next to the title column.

[image]

> **UPDATE**
>   I "Single Line of Text" column pretty much works the same way.

[image]

I've added a  new column at the end and modified the code as follows.

```
<script src="/./SiteAssets/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(8) > a').each(function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("TEST: " + getLink);
        $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().children().children().removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick").attr("href",getLink);
    });
});
</script>
```

> Make sure to include the *jquery-1.8.3.min.js* file

Comment: No, We have so many Hyperlink column exist. when we click on "Title" column, it need to open "External path" column link.

Comment: Got it. Please see my edits.

Comment: thanks Jaitsujin, i tried your script. "External path" column is not hyperlinked column, its "single text field" column on my case. Moreover, my columns are not located side by side. i tried different possibilities but it not working, could you please suggest and guide with updated code.

Comment: Yes, let me put something together real quick and I'll update my post.

Comment: Please see my comments after UPDATE.

Comment: really appreciate your help. small doubt and help, in last you mentioned as "Make sure to include the jquery-1.8.3.min.js file", where we need to include and please suggest me on this.. i am new to jquery.

Comment: That's no problem.
Either replace the first script tag with the following,
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
or download the jquery file and change the path to your local source. In my case SiteAssets.
<script src=".../SiteAssets/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

Regardless, you script should look like the one above.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot of your list view?

Comment: List view screenshot attached on top. Note: external path column is not in our view but it exists on the list. please suggest now.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes it a little more complicated.

Comment: The only two options I can think of are either  
**Option 1**: Hide the "Link" column in your view. This way the code above will still work. Or  
**Option 2**: Create a custom workflow in SP Designer that sets the "Title" columns text to your link. (Set field in current item) and than apply some code that will replace the href with the title columns content. Downside is that you'll the title will get replaced.